# how can get other Country Time in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

i'm beginner swift developer and i want to get user FIPS country codes like "EN" then apps Hour change to that country Time.

```
let CountryTime = String(NSDate.date(*/"EN"*/)) // -> return England Time
```

how can do it ?

Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: The country code might not be sufficient. Consider that the US got 9 time zones. An `(NS)Date` instance is a point in time based on UTC. It doesn't have time zones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following **TimeZone.init** Returns a time zone initialized with a given identifier.If identifier is an unknown identifier, then returns nil.

```
let timezone = TimeZone.init(identifier: "America/Los_Angeles")
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
dateFormatter.timeZone = timezone
print(dateFormatter.string(from: Date()))
```

Also to check the timeZone identifier list you can use this to get list.

```
print("Time zone list %@",TimeZone.knownTimeZoneIdentifiers)
```